# Types of amplifier - what is the difference?

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, amplifier, buffer, gain

What is the difference between an open loop amplifier and a voltage follower (unity gain buffer)?

Comment: stevenvh's answer to [your previous question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/31943/why-is-feedback-resistor-required-in-op-amp-circuits) answer this well.

Comment: Did you try to research about it?

Comment: @clabacchio nope, why research when you can ask people questions cheaply and have the answer with no effort, right? Isn't it logical, I think it is the correct thing to do...

Comment: I posted this after recieving a reply on a previous question: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/31888/basic-frequency-control-circuit. I did google both amplifiers but wanted a direct comparison, which I could not find. stevenvh had not answered any of my questions at the time of this question's posting. Please do not assume I am trying to cheat answers out of fellow users. I am new to electronics.stackexchange.com and am a novice at all things electronic. I apologise for the way my question appears to lack consideration. I would delete this question if it was not already answered

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*I just posted this as an answer to another question, but I can reuse it here :-) (without the part about the non-inverting amplifier).*

**edit**
*Oops, I hadn't noticed the question is from the same person as the other one.*

Let's look at the most simple feedback situation:

[image]

The opamp will amplify the difference between \$V_+\$ and \$V_-\$:

\$ V_{OUT} = 100 000 \times (V_+ - V_-) \$

Now \$V_+ = V_{IN}\$ and \$V_- = V_{OUT}\$, then

\$ V_{OUT} = 100 000 \times (V_{IN} - V_{OUT}) \$

or, rearranging:

\$ V_{OUT} = \dfrac{100 000}{100 000 + 1} \times V_{IN}\$

That's as good as

\$ V_{OUT} = V_{IN}\$

This is a **voltage follower**, a \$\times\$1 amplifier, which is mostly used to get a high input impedance and a low output impedance.

The feedback reduces the very high amplification to \$\times\$1. Note that the high amplification is needed to get \$ V_{OUT}\$ as close as possible to \$V_{IN}\$.

The open loop amplifier will have the high amplification you can see in the transfer function

\$ V_{OUT} = 100 000 \times (V_+ - V_-) \$

Comment: People learn much here right? It's like you are having a lesson with your grasshopper :)

Comment: @abdullah - I think he asked this without even waiting for answers to the other question...

Comment: Ah, this is so lame.. Anyways, you get a +1 from me for all your efforts.

Comment: @abdullah - Thanks! OK, this one was not so hard, mostly copy and paste, but the other answer I typed out completely all by myself! ;-)

Comment: @stevenvh I really appreciate you helping this beginner out. Thanks