# Making a notch filter fo 500Hz frequency

Tags: analog, filter

I am trying to make a notch filter which blocks 500Hz, I beleive it should look like the circuit below. Any idea how can I find the proper values to make it not to pass 500Hz? I tried to give random values in LTSPICE but no success yet!

[image]

Comment: If that one you show is a bandpass, swapping the feedback network with the input network should give you the band stop. That is because the feedback network inverts the transfer function.

Comment: Have you tried with the capacitor and resistor values from stevenvh's answer?

Comment: Not yet, I'll do soon and report back. I know that the steven's circuit is what I need but I am forced to use my own circuit to achive a notch filter (this is an assignement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never seen this circuit before, and I haven't analyzed it. In any case your opamp doesn't have DC feedback, so any input offset will make the output clip to the rails. See also [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/31888/basic-frequency-control-circuit).

You don't need an opamp for a notch filter, they're often made as a **twin T-filter**:

[image]

The center frequency is

\$ f_C = \dfrac{1}{2 \pi R C} \$

The disadvantage of this is a low Q. The following active twin T-filter has adjustable Q:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

TI offers an op amp design guide (pdf, link below).  Ref Section 16-6 for band-rejection.  As with most things, using an op amp gives you more design freedom than a passive circuit.

http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slod006b/slod006b.pdf

Comment: References are nice, and the document you refer to is an excellent one. But I think you should add more information in the answer itself.

Comment: @FedericoRusso, Sorry, I'm no expert on these applications.  I just happened to know of the reference.